# Installing Play On Linux, WINE and iTunes

Tags: 16.04, wine, playonlinux

I want to install iTunes on Ubuntu 16.04 and I read that i had to install it with Play on Linux. So I installed Play on Linux and when having run it i get this:

```
"PlayOnLinux cannot find wine (from Wine)
You should install it to use PlayOnLinux".
```

So now to install WINE I ran `sudo apt-get install wine` and got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14)
           Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Why do you want iTunes?

Comment: To download some music for my iphone

Comment: that will not work, iTunes on Play on Linux cannot sync to an iPhone.

Comment: So what do you offer?

Comment: You could install windows as well, or simply download it over WiFi. Why is the cable sync required? I've not ever plugged my phone into a computer to sync data - only to charge it. Unless you have very slow internet I would have thought you could get by.

Comment: well if you're buying music then from the iTunes Store app.

Comment: But I don't want to pay money for music for that reason i wanted to install ITunes

Comment: Do you already own that music then? If you bought it with iTunes you can restore purchases in the app. If you bought it externally you cannot transfer it from your Ubuntu computer to your iPhone - it's not possible.